# Should I use Objective-C garbage collection when writing for 10.5+?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection

When writing fairly typical Mac code in an OS X 10.5+ environment, what are the disadvantages to using garbage collection?

So far everything else I've written has been either 10.4 compatible or on the iPhone, so I've become fairly comfortable with retain/release, but now that I'm working on a larger project that's 10.5 only I'm wondering if there are any downsides to just going ahead and using the Objective-C 2.0 garbage collector.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are writing new Cocoa code and targeting Mac OS X 10.5, use Objective-C garbage collection.

If you are writing some code that may also need to run on the iPhone, you can write *and test* that code for both models very easily by keeping that code in a separate framework, writing it with property `-retain` and `-release` use, and setting both your framework and your unit test target for it to *GC-supported* rather than *GC-only*.

Xcode will run your unit test bundle twice, once with GC on and once with GC off, and your framework will be usable under both execution models.  Then if you eventually want to bring that model-level code to the iPhone, you can put it in an iPhone-targeted static library or include it directly in your iPhone project.

Regardless of whether you're considering running your code on the iPhone, though, you should definitely target garbage collection if your application will require Leopard.  It will ease development and the Objective-C garbage collector performs quite well.

Answer (score 2):

If there is the possibility to port your application to the iPhone, you shouldn't use it.

Garbage collection **might** have adverse effect on performance if you have special use cases. Without GC, you have precise control on destruction of the object, which is not the case GC world. In most projects, it's worth it to turn on GC as it's less error prone and easier.

In **theory**, memory management without GC can always be faster that with GC, however, it's not the case in most practical applications (since GC is usually more optimized that human being).

Comment: In theory GC could be faster! It's the case when system doesn't need to free memory before your program quits - then you get faster allocation (just next chunk off the heap) and never spend time on releasing memory.

Comment: Yeah, sure. But in theory, you can always write a GC that manages your memory in a non-GC environment. ;)

Comment: no, a GC cannot reclaim memory like a non-GC system. It never knows when to reclaim until it does the collection. Its possible to have a mix of both, allocating from the heap and freeing when it goes out of scope (similar to using() constructs), but not using "pure" GC.

Comment: Your comment is simply untrue.  Automatic collection performs better than manual collection in many cases.  (Because collection is grouped into one operation, rather than done ad-hoc whenever an object is no longer in use.)

Comment: Lot of the performance penalty in GC programs comes from the higher memory requirements. More used memory means more cache misses and they are very expensive. Also GC programs are usually written not very optimized for memory reuse. But this is a problems of programmers becaming lazy and is not technically GC related.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer handling memory management myself, simply because I like to have that level of control. I know from experience in other languages (C#) that GC doesn't allow you to completely ignore memory issues, and that's the same in Cocoa with things like weak references and callbacks using (void *) where the object isn't explicitly being owned by another object. You're basically trading one set of challenges (memory leaks) for another. Personally I don't tend to make too many memory management mistakes these days, and the ones I do make are pretty easy to track down.

There are some situations (such as implementing data source methods for an NSOutlineView, where you don't want to retain the object being provided to the outline view) where I've thought GC would be really helpful, but I haven't done any real tests with it yet.

Apple lists some other advantages and disadvantages in the [GC programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcAdoption.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002457).

Comment: He's not doing it to optimize.

Comment: Don't you mean to say, "ignore memory issues, and that's NOT the same in Cocoa"?

Answer (score -1):

GC is deprecated starting with 10.8.  It was actually never a good idea to adopt this technology, cheerleading aside, because performance and stability goals were never met.

Managing memory "manually" is actually very simple, because the management code can largely be factored out.  My code base has <1% code related to memory management, and that's larger than it needs to be.  So I am also skeptical about ARC, just because the problem it's solving is so tiny that even fairly small gotchas with the technology make it less than worthwhile.

Comment: It's not true that it was *never* a good idea. Both technologies have the same goal; most of the code written for both looks the same, and they're conceptually equivalent when it comes to treating assignment as ownership. Treating the percentage of memory management code as proof of its ease is highly inaccurate. Certainly, as the percentage goes up, the likelihood of a bug increases, but it only takes one line (or one missing line) to introduce a serious memory management error.

Comment: Having good goals does not make something a good idea, road to hell being paved with good intentions and all that.  GC simply never worked properly, which is why adopting it was never a good idea.  In justifying ARC, Chris Lattner described the GC's shortcomings:  http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2011/Jun/msg00013.html  These shortcomings were always present, they did not just suddenly appear once ARC was introduced.  This venue is too short for proofs, but the same argument you apply to memory management applies to all other code as well, so your argument is specious.

Comment: GC's shortcomings were documented; that was never at issue. The total line count of retain/release code is irrelevant as an argument in favor of manual memory management because it only takes one retain cycle or other casual mistake to introduce an error. Sometimes, we become attached to something due to the time we've invested in it, and we become distrustful of new things. I believe that opposing idiomatic modern Objective-C, which uses ARC, is standing on the wrong side of history for the wrong reasons.